# Do we use verb + s/es after singular they?

Tags: american-english, grammatical-number, singular-they

I am not an American. I think it is in America where they invented the idea of singular they. You don't know the gender of someone, you refer to him/her as they. I am thinking if I should use the verb alone or verb + s/es after a singular they.

An example to highlight my idea.

> Someone named Ekadh close voted my question. They **think/thinks** my question is off-topic.

Should I use think/thinks here? I know Ekadh is a person, one person, whose gender I don't know.

Comment: They always uses think, not thinks.

Comment: @Lambie So singular they and plural they are grammatically same?

Answer (score 1):

Correct: They **think**

'They think' is in the simple present tense. We do not add 's' or 'es' to the verb if the subject is 'singular they'.

'They' always takes a plural verb.

Someone is standing at the door, **are**n't **they**? In this sentence 'is' agrees with
'someone' and 'are' agrees with 'they'. But 'they' refers to someone.

We use 'they' when we don't know whether a person is male or female.

Comment: Please stop adding repeat answers.